# How to open PDF file in Unity iOS?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have application on Android. I want to convert it to iOS. I made this in Unity. There is one problem. I can't open pdf file in iOS.

`UnityAndroidOpenUrl.AndroidOpenUrl.OpenFile(path, "application/pdf");`

This is the code line for Android. I can open pdf file with this line.
Application.OpenURL doesn't work with local files.

How can i do it this for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS apparently you have to go native through [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller).

You can create a native plugin like e.g.

```
Assets/Plugins/iOS/iOSOpenURL.mm
```

with the following content

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FileOpener : NSObject

- (void)openFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;

@end

@implementation FileOpener

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (void)openFileAtPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
    controller.delegate = (id<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>)self;
    [controller presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}

@end

// NOTE: parts below here are coming from the example under https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Examples/iPhoneNativeCodeSample.zip

static FileOpener* fileOpener = nil;

// Converts C style string to NSString
NSString* CreateNSString (const char* string)
{
    if (string)
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String: string];
    else
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String: ""];
}

// When native code plugin is implemented in .mm / .cpp file, then functions
// should be surrounded with extern "C" block to conform C function naming rules
extern "C" 
{
    void _OpenFile(const char* path)
    {
        if (fileOpener == nil)
            fileOpener = [FileOpener alloc];

        [fileOpener openFileAtPath: CreateNSString(path)];
    }
}
```

which basically forwards your request to the mentioned `UIDocumentInteractionController`

Then next to it have according `c#` file like e.g.

```
Assets/Plugins/iOS/iOSOpenURL.cs
```

with this content

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class iOSOpenURL
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void _OpenFile(string path);

    public static void OpenFile(string path)
    {
#if UNITY_IOS && !UNITY_EDITOR
        _OpenFile(path);
#else
        throw new OperationNotSupportedException("Only works on iOS!");
#endif
    }
}
```

then back in the Unity editor click on the native `iOSOpenURL` (it should have a plugin icon) and in the Inspector further configure it - since using according folder names it should have selected only `iOS` as the supported target platform already - meaning for any other build target this plugin will not be included into the `__Internal.dll`

See also [See also Building plug-ins for iOS](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

And then finally together with [Unity-Android-Files-Opener](https://github.com/Mihail5412/Unity-Android-Files-Opener) for Android you already have you can basically combine them into something like e.g.

```
public static class LocalFileUtility
{
    public static void OpenFile(string filePath)
    {
#if UNITY_ANDOIRD && !UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityAndroidOpenUrl.AndroidOpenUrl.OpenFile(filePath, "application/pdf");
#elif UNITY_IOS && !UNITY_EDITOR
        iOSOpenURL.OpenFile(filePath);
#else
        Application.OpenURL(filePath);
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this solution. There is no error Unity side. I builded it in iOS platform and then, I uploaded .xcodeproj to Xcode then archived it. Gave me this error: Undefined Symbols: _openFileAtPath, referenced from: _iOSOpenURL_openFileAtPath_mAC1e.... continues.

Comment: Hey @ozzyys I read the [linked manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html) again and apparently you still have to wrap your methods with an `extern "C" { }` block .. I followed the example you can find at the very bottom of that page and updated the code here .. hope this is now as it is supposed to be ^^

Comment: For "self = [super init]" line give this error: Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method in the init family.

Comment: @ozzyys hm can you try again? I had `Init` instead of `init` .. besides that it is exactly what the example does

Comment: I think we found. It should be (id)init instead of (id)Init. I will test the application in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a followup to [derHugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76613571/3545273).

---

I tried to implement derHugo's codes, but I seem to run into an error during execution:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController delegate must implement documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: to allow preview
```

To avoid this, one should add to derHugo's code:

1/ in the interface :

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller;
```

2/ in the implementation

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
    return UnityGetGLViewController();
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34730690)

Comment: I know. It was first intended as a comment to amend the existing Answer, as it is directly relate to that answer. However, as I don't have enough réputation points, answering was all I could do.